# unity3d 5.3.5 breaks photon

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, photon

I recently updated unity to version 5.3.5 from the previuos version
(i think it was 5.3.4, logically it should be),
first errors are gone after i click the clear button, except for two.

They are about some classes called "photonpeer" and "iphotonpeerlistener" that some scripts enherit from, and they cant find them.
Both erros come from the photon built in chat system, and i built my own chat system to fit my needs better, so i delete the photon chat system (forgot to do so earlier in game development). First two errors fixed.

Now a bunch of new errors come up, i hit clear and see this:

Full Text Format:

```
Assets/Photon Unity Networking/Plugins/PhotonNetwork/LoadbalancingPeer.cs(27,40): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `PhotonPeer' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?  

Assets/Photon Unity Networking/Plugins/PhotonNetwork/NetworkingPeer.cs(20,52): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `IPhotonPeerListener' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?  

Assets/Photon Unity Networking/Plugins/PhotonNetwork/PingCloudRegions.cs(17,31): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `PhotonPing' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?  

Assets/Photon Unity Networking/Plugins/PhotonNetwork/SocketUdp.cs(22,32): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `IPhotonSocket' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

### I cant find the classes:

```
PhotonPeer
IPhotonPeerListener
PhotonPing
IPhotonSocket
```

And so not fix them...
What should i do?

Any help is apreciated greatly!
Cencere thanks in advance:

Alfred E
Sweden

Comment: @JoeBlow photon is a placeholder, i am going to replace it when the game is actually playable

Comment: Yeah... I don't have "a few lines of code", I have ~500 lines of code specially engineered to fit the very specific needs, I use the distance between players to determine the amount of the message they get, and I would have to rewrite the entire system to use U.N. Instead. I'm trying to focus on problems like, the physics engine not registering collision properly on objects that are smaller than .1 unit in any dimension. I think it's great that you are trying to convince people to use U.N. but I have no time to sit and rewrite that entire thing __Plus__ code the positional part right now

Comment: HI AE.  Sorry to waste your time.  If you think I was trying to "convince someone to use AE", sorry for the confusion.  Good luck.

Comment: Do you use latest version of PUN? Missing dependencies in chat was resolved recently. Photon chat shares dlls with PUN. Most likely you removed these dlls. Delete *.cs only if really need it.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it